# Axios doesn't work on safari 10.1 and sometime on mozila 56

Tags: javascript, laravel, safari, vue.js, axios

I am having issues with my laravel vue2 website. I am using axios for login and other form submissions. Axios works nicely on chrome and mozila but some users reported they get 'Error: Network error' in mozila and `undefined` in safari 10.1.
Here is the code I am using.

```
login(){

        this.show=true;
        var self=this;
        axios({
              method: 'post',
              url: this.sl+'/user/login',
              data: this.user
            })
             .then(function (response) {
                 self.show=false;
                 if(response.data.status=200){
                     self.showSucc(self.t('Done'), response.data.done)
                     setTimeout( ()=>{
                            window.location = response.data.url;                     
                           }, 1000 );
                 }


              })
             .catch(function (error) {

                self.show=false;
              alert(error); // shows undefined 
              alert(error.error);
                  if (error.response) {
                    if(error.response.data.password){
                      self.showWarn(self.t('Error'), error.response.data.password[0]);
                    }
                    if(error.response.data.error){
                      self.showWarn(self.t('Error'), error.response.data.error);
                    }

                  //console.log(error.response.data.password);

                } else if (error.request) {
                self.show=false;
                  console.log("Something went wrong");
                } else {
                self.show=false;    
                  console.log('Error', error.message);
                }

            });
     }


alert(error); // shows undefined
```

How can I make axios works? Note: I added polyfill for older browsers and it solved IE 11 problems.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem it was `Preflight request` problem. Some browsers send OPTION request before sending actual ajax request. So all I have to do is ensure the OPTION request get a status code of 200. That's it.